# Select2 input box does not refresh default value

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 jquery plugin attached to a SELECT element. That Select2 has the allowClear attribute.

When I select a value in the list, the corresponding input box is not set to reflect the selected value. The selected value is set by the JQGRID edit form.

This is how I am creating the select column:

```
        {name: "responsable", width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select', editrules: {required: false}, editoptions: {style: 'width: 310px', value: '{{ usuarios }}', dataInit: function(el) {
                    $(el).select2(
                            {
                                placeholder: "-[Seleccione responsable]-",
                                width: 310,
                                allowClear: true
                            });
                }}, stype: 'select', searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq'], value: '{{ usuarios }}'}},
```

When I first open an edit dialog, the input box is set with the value from the grid, but when I select another element, the old value is shown in the input text, however, when I expand the select list, the right value appears selected.

How can I solve this?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: Did you come up with a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Select2 binds to the underlying change event. If you change the value programmatically (via `$.val`, for example), this event doesn't get triggered, so you have to trigger it manually:

`$(el).val('some new value').trigger('change')`

that will cause select2 to pick up on the change and update properly.

More info can be found in Select2's [examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) page, under `programmatic access`.